# UIImageview not updating once camera picture is taken but when gallery image is selected, camera picture shows for a second

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift5

I am having an issue while displaying camera captured image in an image view where delegates are set and being called "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo".

I have two button for the user interaction (camera picture & from gallery), once I take picture from camera and then select any other image from gallery; the camera picture taken earlier is shown for a second. I tried searching a lot but no luck so far.

Can anyone please advise what am I missing. Following is the code for reference.

```
  @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.openCamera()
  }

  @IBAction func galleryButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.openGallary()

  }


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    initialLayout()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.lblPreview.isHidden = true
    self.imageTake.isHidden = true
    self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
  }

  //
  //MARK: - Internal Methods
  func initialLayout() {

    self.cameraButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.galleryButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    self.uploadButtonOutlet.layer.cornerRadius = 20

  }


//MARK: - Open the camera
  func openCamera(){

    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera)){

      imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
      //If you dont want to edit the photo then you can set allowsEditing to false
      imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
      imagePicker.delegate = self
      imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
      imagePicker.cameraDevice = .rear
      self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else{
      let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
      self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

  //MARK: - Choose image from camera roll

  func openGallary(){

    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }


extension UploadTimesheetViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:  [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{

      self.lblPreview.isHidden = false
      self.imageTake.isHidden = false
      self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
        self.imageTake.image = editedImage
        self.imageTake.setNeedsLayout()
      })

      // self.imageTake.image = editedImage
    }

    //Dismiss the UIImagePicker after selection
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }

  func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    picker.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

I also tried with the following code as well but still the same result.

```
var finalImage:UIImage?

if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
    finalImage = image
}else {
    finalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
}

self.lblPreview.isHidden = false
self.imageTake.isHidden = false
self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
self.imageTake.image = finalImage

//Dismiss the UIImagePicker after selection
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: although the delegate is called after taking camera picture and image is set against self.imageTake.image but on screen nothing shows at all but every time when I select image from gallery it works perfectly.

Comment: Anyone please ?

Comment: This is the first time i am being disappointed as no reply so far. Where is everyone?

Comment: code updated but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You set image on the imageView after 1 second delay. That's why the previous image shown for a second.

Remove the delay and show the image instantly. Like this

```
if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {

  self.lblPreview.isHidden = false
  self.imageTake.isHidden = false
  self.uploadButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
  self.imageTake.image = editedImage
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  })

})
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion but it is still not working. same result no image initially but when I select any from gallery afterwards then camera taken image shown for a second. Only camera taken image is not showing at all

Comment: Would you please put some delay to dismiss the pickerview. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: I did and hence the reason it shows the camera taken image for a second when I select picture from gallery. still camera taken picture is not shown in image view every time I try it.